# Creating a Dynamic Range with a Macro

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2003, vba

```
YearMth   Region   Employee   Item     Units     Unit Cost     Total 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
2006-12   DC       Jones      Pen Set  700       1.99          1,393 
2006-12   NY       Peterson   Binder   85        19.99         1,699 
2006-12   DC       Howard     Pen Set  62        4.99          309 
2006-12   DC       Gill       Pen      58        19.99         1,159 
2006-12   NY       Anderson   Binder   10        4.99          50 
2006-12   NY       Anderson   Pen Set  19        2.99          57
```

Using this data how would I create a Dynamic Range using a Macro.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what you want to do! But here's an example

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyDynamicRange", 
    RefersToR1C1:= "=OFFSET(Sheet1!R2C2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!R2C2:R200C2),1)"
```

This range will contain all your Regions.